# jQuery AJAX & XML getting node value

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have the following code that grabs the text in xml nodes

```
$(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
     alert($(this).find('author').text());
});
```

This will alert what ever text happens to be in each `<name>`

I am struggling to get the text value in a node that looks like this -

```
<im:name>
```

Changing my code to look like this -

```
$(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
     alert($(this).find('im:name').text());
});
```

Doesn't work, can someone point me in the right direction please.

I have tried searching but don't know what to call a node that is in this format!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the `:`.

```
alert($(this).find('im\\:name').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Y2ff/